# Submit button next to textfield with same height

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to achieve a perfect alignment with a submit button next to a text field, each with its own font size. The problem is that I get different results in different browsers, (my site is supporting IE7+ and all modern browsers).

Here´s what I´m working on: http://jsfiddle.net/bxTfn/18/

It seems to be working in Chrome and IE, but the submit button is 1px too short in FF.

Thanks for your help.

CLARIFICATION: I want the text box to have font size 14px and the submit 12px.

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bxTfn/24/
This seems to be working in Chrome, FF and IE7 but not in IE8 and IE9 where the submit jumps down 1px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

box-sizing might be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/23CE8/1/

This worked for me in Chrome and in IE8, however IE8 now mis-aligns the input and the submit button (although they're the same height). I added vertical-align: middle to both elements (although it could be on their parent container) in order to resolve that.

If you want IE7 to use box-sizing you'll need some polyfills, there's a link to some here from Paul Irish's blog here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ he also explains some of the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, the following changes to your `CSS` seems to line them up perfectly:

```
input[type=text] {
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 14px;    
}

input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
}​
```

Comment: The thing is that I don´t what them to have the same font size.

Comment: further to your edit, I noticed that tweaking the border of the button seems to align them. Don't have definitive values as I couldn't recreate it yet!

Comment: Each browser (sometimes on each OS) may use different values for the button chrome/border/padding so trying to tweak margins and padding is probably a losing game unless you use conditional style sheets.