# Make HTML Text Field & Button Same Height with CSS - Not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make both my text field and button the same height (40px) with CSS.

Why are the text field and button different heights even though they are both set to 40px?

My code is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/xkmmP/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#textQuizFillBlankUserAnswer {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
#buttonQuizFillBlankSubmit {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="textQuizFillBlankUserAnswer">
<input type="button" id="buttonQuizFillBlankSubmit" value="&gt;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`text` and `button` inputs use a different box model.  The button uses `border-box`, so the border is actually considered part of the box model (i.e. height).  You can get around this by changing one of the models.  Perhaps add `box-sizing: border-box` to the text input (you will need `-moz-box-sizing` too).

http://jsfiddle.net/xkmmP/

Answer (score 2):

add this to :

```
#textQuizFillBlankUserAnswer {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;  // This line
    vertical-align: middle;  // and this line
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396290/submit-button-next-to-textfield-with-same-height)